# Reporting an exception in Boost::test

Tags: c++, boost-test

Using the `boost::test` framework, is there a way to detect if an exception (of some type) has been thrown from a function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you specify that an exception should be expected using Boost.Test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172854/how-do-you-specify-that-an-exception-should-be-expected-using-boost-test)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking to test that a function correctly throws under some circumstances?
If so

```
BOOST_CHECK_THROW( function(), exception_type );
```

will do it. You can use

```
BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION( function(), exception_type, predicate )
```

to call an arbitrary predicate on the exception when it's caught and

```
BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW( function() )
```

to ensure a function doesn't throw.

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html